# How to introduce delay between Pod restarts in a statefulset?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I am using the below command to restart Pods in a statefulset

```bash
kubectl rollout restart statefulset ts
```

If I have to introduce a delay between pod rotation, is there an argument or any other method to achieve it? I am using a sidecar that updates the Pod IP address to a configuration file, if the Pod restarts before the IP address is updated in the config file, the service is not healthy. Looking for a way to introduce a delay between pod restarts/pod rotations.

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: typesense
  namespace: typesense
  labels:
    service: typesense
    app: typesense
spec:
  serviceName: ts
  podManagementPolicy: Parallel
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      service: typesense
      app: typesense
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        service: typesense
        app: typesense
    spec:
      serviceAccountName: typesense-service-account
      securityContext:
        fsGroup: 2000
        runAsUser: 10000
        runAsGroup: 3000
        runAsNonRoot: true
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 300
      containers:
        - name: typesense
          envFrom:
            # - configMapRef: 
            #     name: typesense-config
            - secretRef:
                name: typesense-secret
          image: typesense/typesense:0.23.0.rc43
          command:
            - "/opt/typesense-server"
            - "-d"
            - "/usr/share/typesense/data"
            - "--api-port"
            - "8108"
            - "--peering-port"
            - "8107"
            - "--nodes"
            - "/usr/share/typesense/nodes"
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8108
              name: http
          resources:
            requests:
              memory: 100Mi
              cpu: "100m"
            limits:
              memory: 1Gi
              cpu: "1000m"
          volumeMounts:
            - name: nodeslist
              mountPath: /usr/share/typesense
            - name: data
              mountPath: /usr/share/typesense/data
        - name: typesense-node-resolver
          image: alasano/typesense-node-resolver
          command:
            - "/opt/tsns"
            - "-namespace=typesense"
          volumeMounts:
          - name: nodeslist
            mountPath: /usr/share/typesense
      volumes:
        - name: nodeslist
          emptyDir: {}
  volumeClaimTemplates:
    - metadata:
        name: data
      spec:
        accessModes:
          - ReadWriteOnce
        storageClassName: nfs
        resources:
          requests:
            storage: 1Gi
```

You can find the full manifest [here](https://github.com/ivishalgandhi/learn/blob/main/k8s/typesense/ts.yaml).

Comment: Could you include statefulset manifest in the question?

Comment: https://github.com/ivishalgandhi/learn/blob/main/k8s/typesense/ts.yaml done. Thank you.

Comment: I would use readiness probes for that. Make the container not ready until the sidecar is done and the StatefulSet will wait (forever) for the current Pod to be ready before restarting the next one.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you could try `terminationGracePeriodSeconds` and `preStop` hook with following command.

```
command: [ "/bin/bash", "-c", "sleep 30" ]
```

It introduces a 30 second delay after your container receive stop from control plane. With terminationGracePeriodSeconds, control plane won't force kill your container within the period.

The complete example should look like this:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: test
  labels:
    app: test
spec:
  replicas: 1
  serviceName: "test"
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: test
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: test
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: nginx
        name: test
      lifecycle:
        preStop:
          exec:
            command: [ "/bin/bash", "-c", "sleep 60" ]
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 60
```

Comment: Carl Tsai, a link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it is there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you are linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](/help/deleted-answers)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe using [init container](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/init-containers/) ?

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: typesense
  namespace: typesense
  labels:
    service: typesense
    app: typesense
spec:
  serviceName: ts
  podManagementPolicy: Parallel
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      service: typesense
      app: typesense
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        service: typesense
        app: typesense
    spec:
      serviceAccountName: typesense-service-account
      securityContext:
        fsGroup: 2000
        runAsUser: 10000
        runAsGroup: 3000
        runAsNonRoot: true
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 300
      initContainers:
        - name: init-myservice
          image: busybox:1.34.1
          command: [
              "echo",
              "ip",
              "to",
              "config",
              "file",,
            ]
      containers:
        - name: typesense
          envFrom:
            # - configMapRef: 
            #     name: typesense-config
            - secretRef:
                name: typesense-secret
          image: typesense/typesense:0.23.0.rc43
          command:
            - "/opt/typesense-server"
            - "-d"
            - "/usr/share/typesense/data"
            - "--api-port"
            - "8108"
            - "--peering-port"
            - "8107"
            - "--nodes"
            - "/usr/share/typesense/nodes"
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8108
              name: http
          resources:
            requests:
              memory: 100Mi
              cpu: "100m"
            limits:
              memory: 1Gi
              cpu: "1000m"
          volumeMounts:
            - name: nodeslist
              mountPath: /usr/share/typesense
            - name: data
              mountPath: /usr/share/typesense/data
        - name: typesense-node-resolver
          image: alasano/typesense-node-resolver
          command:
            - "/opt/tsns"
            - "-namespace=typesense"
          volumeMounts:
          - name: nodeslist
            mountPath: /usr/share/typesense
      volumes:
        - name: nodeslist
          emptyDir: {}
  volumeClaimTemplates:
    - metadata:
        name: data
      spec:
        accessModes:
          - ReadWriteOnce
        storageClassName: nfs
        resources:
          requests:
            storage: 1Gi
```